# how to read data from excel, having only one column

Tags: java, excel

//method contains:

public Object[][] getExcelData(String excelLocation) {

```
    Object[][] dataSet = null;

    try {

        file = new FileInputStream(excelLocation);

        wrkbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        wrkbook.close();

        sheet = wrkbook.getSheetAt(0);
```

// to get total active row count

```
        int rowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
```

// to get total active column count

```
        int colNum = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

        dataSet = new Object[rowNum][colNum];

        for (int i = 0; i <rowNum; i++) {

            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);

            for (int j = 0; j <=colNum; j++) {

                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);

                String value = String.valueOf(cell);

                dataSet[i][j] = value;
            }

        }
        return dataSet;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
```

// return null if for any exception

Comment: You have to provide more information. For example are you using Apache Poi? How is this code failing? Is the compiler showing an error? Also - the code shown alone is not complete and would be a within a method. Do you have a class you're running it from?

Comment: I'm using Apache Poi . and This is giving only 1 result.

Comment: Immediately returning a value from a loop will stop looping at the first result. Maybe replace `return cellvalue;` by `System.out.println(cellvalue);`.

Comment: how should I handle to return all values? ---@deHaar

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the column values from the spreadsheet as a 2d array, change the signature of your method to return an array of type String[][], iterate over each row of the spreadsheet, adding the value of all of its columns to the array, and return the Array when you're done.  I haven't tested this but it should be pretty close:

```
public static String[][] getDataSetAsArray(XSSFSheet pSheet) {
    int iRowCount = pSheet.getLastRowNum();
    int iColumnCount = pSheet.getRow(pSheet.getFirstRowNum()).getLastCellNum();
    String[][] strDataVals = new String[iRowCount][iColumnCount];
    for (int r = 0; r <= iRowCount; r++) {
        XSSFRow row = pSheet.getRow(r);
        for (int c = 0; c <= iColumnCount; c++) {
            strDataVals[r][c] = row.getCell(c).getStringCellValue();
        }
    }
    return strDataVals;
}
```

Comment: I want to store it into an 2d array

Comment: I have only one column data and want to store data as [0][0], [1][1], [2][2].....

Comment: Using what you posted in your comment, these array elements would all be null:
    [1][0]
    [2][0]
    [2][1]

If you only have one column, it seems like your array structure would be:
    [0][0] (column 1, row 1)
    [0][1] (column 1, row 2)
    [0][2] (column 1, row 3)
    [0][3] (column 1, row 4)
    etc ...

If that's true, it's not clear why you need the 2nd dimension.

Comment: you are correct.. the array structure would be: [0][0] (row 0, column 0) [1][0] (row 1, column 0) [2][0] (row 2, column 0) [3][0] (row 3, column 0) etc.

Comment: You never clarified why you need the results in a 2d array when (from what you've posted) it seems as though a 1d array or even a List object would work.  In any case, I think the code I posted should give you enough information to figure the rest out - even if it's not a perfect solution.